# Tango needs google web services?

Tags: google-project-tango

our project is in China, where all google services are blocked.

does Tango need any google services, or is it self-sufficient and is able to operate on its own? if it needs services, it is basically useless to our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically,
Normal Project Tango device's features didn't need online google services.
MotionTracking, AreaLearning and Depth should do well.
you can download the sample apps sources code on here

like c samples :
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/
try that, it won't need online google services.

But there maybe some apps which integrated Tango feature with other google services do.

Unfortunately, since Google Services is blocked in China, you can't get the BSP OTA and Play store apps updated, which means at some point you can't get new features and bugs fixed on your devices.

If you need further help. better contact project-tango-help@google.com.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it does not. I can confirm that I've been using my devkit offline most of the time.

More generally, the core Tango services are all hosted on the device, and they were preinstalled on my devkit when I got it about 3 weeks ago. However, updates to these services come OTA via Google Play.

The three services Tango provides are motion tracking, area learning and depth sensing. Depth sensing is provided directly by the sensors, and motion tracking obviously cant be done online in a performant way. AFAIK, area learning too happens offline, but you can find more info [here](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/area-learning).